# How to make VS code terminal use .bash_profile instead of .bashrc

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am on `macOS`, I have set up git aliases in my `.bash_profile` and I want `VS Code` to run its terminal using `.bash_profile` instead of global `.bashrc`.